# Switching to assembly in gdb

Tags: assembly, gdb

Is there is any way to switch to assembly when debugging a C or C++ program in gdb ? (Given that all source files and their corresponding assembly files are available)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902901/show-current-assembly-instruction-in-gdb

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a way to disassemble a function or a certain section of code, is that what you are after?

The command to do so would be `disassemble <function name>` or a memory location.

Is this what you are referring to?

```
(gdb) help disassemble
Disassemble a specified section of memory.
Default is the function surrounding the pc of the selected frame.
With a single argument, the function surrounding that address is dumped.
Two arguments are taken as a range of memory to dump.
```

Answer (score 74):

You can switch to asm layout in gdb:

```
(gdb) layout asm
```

See [online documentation](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Commands.html#TUI-Commands) for more information.

Comment: This only works for 'TUI' mode.

Comment: Link no longer works

Answer (score 11):

In the new gdb version 7.0, the `disassemble` command can take a new argument `/m` which makes it emit mixed source and disassembly.

Answer (score 4):

Using the disas command will probably do what you want.

According to the internal help, the disas command does the following:

```
Disassemble a specified section of memory.
Default is the function surrounding the pc of the selected frame.
With a single argument, the function surrounding that address is dumped.
Two arguments are taken as a range of memory to dump.
```

Answer (score 1):

That question was also asked in cgdb's googlegroup
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de&fromgroups=#!topic/cgdb-users/E-jZCJiBAQQ

No answer yet on why layout asm doesnt work though

Edit: They posted recently and told that its a feature that isnt implemented yet. (check the link above)