# How to step through Python code to help debug issues?

Tags: python, debugging

In Java/C# you can easily step through code to trace what might be going wrong, and IDE's make this process very user friendly.

Can you trace through python code in a similar fashion?

Comment: For any beginners directed here, see also: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](/q/25385173/4518341) There's also [a second answer there](/a/29457171/4518341) that covers alternatives to a debugger.

Comment: Beginners might also be interested in [using f-strings for debugging](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging) (which may be way easier than using a debugger in many cases)

Answer (score 373, accepted):

Yes! There's a Python debugger called `pdb` just for doing that!

You can launch a Python program through `pdb` via `python -m pdb myscript.py`.

There are a few commands you can then issue, which are documented on the [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) page.

Some useful ones to remember are:

- `b`: set a breakpoint
- `c`: continue debugging until you hit a breakpoint
- `s`: step through the code
- `n`: to go to next line of code
- `l`: list source code for the current file (default: 11 lines including the line being executed)
- `u`: navigate up a stack frame
- `d`: navigate down a stack frame
- `p`: to print the value of an expression in the current context

If you don't want to use a command line debugger, some IDEs like [Pydev](http://pydev.org/), [Wing IDE](https://wingware.com/) or [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) have a GUI debugger. Wing and PyCharm are commercial products, but Wing has a free "Personal" edition, and PyCharm has a free community edition.

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe I'm having a hard time finding a graphical pdb for linux/ubuntu. Am I missing something? I might have to look into making a SublimeText Plugin for it.

Comment: PyCharm is pretty good as a graphical debugger, and its Community Edition is free!

Comment: @ThorSummoner, `pudb` is great for that. Also `pydev`

Comment: `pdb` is not a command line tool. To use it, use `python -m pdb your_script.py`.

Comment: @jdhao I guess it's not standard, but on Ubuntu the `pdb` command is part of the `python` package. In any case, `python -m <module>` is becoming the standard for other things too like `pip`, so it's probably best to use that by default.

Comment: @wjandrea I am using python 3.6.5 on both Ubuntu and Windows. There are no `pdb` binary provided. Which python version are you referring to?

Comment: @jdhao Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04. It's also included in the [`python3` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3&searchon=names) but it's called `pdb3`.

Answer (score 81):

### By using Python Interactive Debugger 'pdb'

First step is to make the Python interpreter enter into the debugging mode.

**A. From the Command Line**

Most straight forward way, running from command line, of python interpreter

```
$ python -m pdb scriptName.py
> .../pdb_script.py(7)<module>()
-> """
(Pdb)
```

**B. Within the Interpreter**

While developing early versions of modules and to experiment it more iteratively.

```
$ python
Python 2.7 (r27:82508, Jul  3 2010, 21:12:11)
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pdb_script
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.run('pdb_script.MyObj(5).go()')
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb)
```

**C. From Within Your Program**

For a big project and long-running module, can start the debugging from inside the program using
`import pdb` and `set_trace()`
like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
#

import pdb

class MyObj(object):
    count = 5
    def __init__(self):
        self.count= 9

    def go(self):
        for i in range(self.count):
            pdb.set_trace()
            print i
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyObj(5).go()
```

**Step-by-Step debugging to go into more internal**

1. Execute the next statement… with **“n”** (next)
2. Repeating the last debugging command… with **ENTER**
3. Quitting it all… with **“q”** (quit)
4. Printing the value of variables… with “p” (print)

   a)  `p a`
5. Turning off the (Pdb) prompt… with **“c”** (continue)
6. Seeing where you are… with **“l”** (list)
7. Stepping into subroutines… with **“s”** (step into)
8. Continuing… but just to the end of the current subroutine… with **“r”** (return)
9. Assign a new value

   a)  `!b = "B"`
10. Set a breakpoint

    a)  `break linenumber`

    b)  `break functionname`

    c)  `break filename:linenumber`
11. Temporary breakpoint

    a)  `tbreak linenumber`
12. Conditional breakpoint

    a)  `break linenumber, condition`

**Note:** All these commands should be executed from **pdb**

For in-depth knowledge, refer:

- https://pymotw.com/2/pdb/
- https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/

Comment: *"Turning off the (Pdb) prompt… with “c” (continue)"* -- That doesn't sound right... The [docs](//docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands) say `c` is *"Continue execution, only stop when a breakpoint is encountered."*

Answer (score 50):

There is a module called 'pdb' in python. At the top of your python script you do

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

and you will enter into debugging mode. You can use 's' to step, 'n' to follow next line similar to what you would do with 'gdb' debugger.

Answer (score 40):

Starting in Python 3.7, you can use the [`breakpoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#breakpoint) built-in function to enter the debugger:

```
foo()
breakpoint()  # drop into the debugger at this point
bar()
```

By default, `breakpoint()` will import [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pdb.html#module-pdb) and call [`pdb.set_trace()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pdb.html#pdb.set_trace). However, you can control debugging behavior via [`sys.breakpointhook()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.breakpointhook) and use of the environment variable [`PYTHONBREAKPOINT`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONBREAKPOINT).

See [PEP 553](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0553/) for more information.

Comment: When I saw `breakpoint` I was excited. But then I learnt that it is essentially just a shortcut for `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and that made me sad. Python devs: please focus on improving PDB with basic GDB features like context lines, persistent command history and tab auto-completion :-)

Comment: @CiroSantilliПутлерКапут六四事 Not really.  By *default* it points to `pdb`.  With appropriate flags it can load other debuggers.  Like `ipdb` (ex: `PYTHONBREAKPOINT=ipdb.set_trace `) or other more advanced debuggers.

Comment: `PYTHONBREAKPOINT=IPython.embed` is really one of my favourites.

Answer (score 14):

### ipdb (IPython debugger)

[ipdb](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb) adds IPython functionality to pdb, offering the following HUGE improvements:

- tab completion
- show more context lines
- syntax highlight

Much like pdg, ipdb is still far from perfect and completely rudimentary if compared to GDB, but it is already a huge improvement over pdb.

Usage is analogous to `pdb`, just install it with:

```
python3 -m pip install --user ipdb
```

and then add to the line you want to step debug from:

```
__import__('ipdb').set_trace(context=21)
```

You likely want to add a shortcut for that from your editor, e.g. for [Vim snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) I have:

```
snippet ipd
    __import__('ipdb').set_trace(context=21)
```

so I can type just `ipd<tab>` and it expands to the breakpoint. Then removing it is easy with `dd` since everything is contained in a single line.

`context=21` increases the number of context lines as explained at: [How can I make ipdb show more lines of context while debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240887/how-can-i-make-ipdb-show-more-lines-of-context-while-debugging/53172956#53172956)

Alternatively, you can also debug programs from the start with:

```
ipdb3 main.py
```

but you generally don't want to do that because:

- you would have to go through all function and class definitions as Python reads those lines
- I don't know how to set the context size there without hacking ipdb. Patch to allow it: https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/pull/155

Or alternatively, as in raw pdb 3.2+ you can set some breakpoints from the command line:

```
ipdb3 -c 'b 12' -c 'b myfunc' ~/test/a.py
```

although `-c c` is broken for some reason: https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/156

`python -m module` debugging has been asked at: [How to debug a Python module run with python -m from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265835/how-to-debug-a-python-module-run-with-python-m-from-the-command-line/53173317#53173317) and since Python 3.7 can be done with:

```
python -m pdb -m my_module
```

Serious missing features of both pdb and ipdb compared to GDB:

- persistent command history across sessions: [Save command history in pdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346419/save-command-history-in-pdb)

ipdb specific annoyances:

- multithreading does not work well if you don't hack some settings...

  - [ipdb, multiple threads and autoreloading programs causing ProgrammingError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580234/ipdb-multiple-threads-and-autoreloading-programs-causing-programmingerror/21176665)
  - https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/51

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04, ipdb==0.11, Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 10):

### VSCode

If you want to use an IDE, this is a good alternative to PyCharm.

1. Install [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/)
2. Install the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), if it's not already installed
3. For example, create a file `mymodule.py` with Python code
4. To set a breakpoint, hover over a line number and click the red dot, or press <kbd>F9</kbd>
5. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to start debugging and select **Python File**

It will stop at the breakpoint and you can do your usual debugging stuff like inspecting the values of variables, either at the tab **VARIABLES** (usually on the left) or by clicking on **Debug Console** (usually at the bottom next to your **Terminal**):

[image: screenshot of VSCode showing debug console during debugging]

*This screenshot shows [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/).*

#### More information

- [Python debugging in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)
- [Getting Started with Python in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)
- [Debugging in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

Answer (score 7):

There exist `breakpoint()` method nowadays, which replaces `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`.

It also has [several new features](https://hackernoon.com/python-3-7s-new-builtin-breakpoint-a-quick-tour-4f1aebc444c), such as possible environment variables.

Answer (score 5):

[Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/) is an online single-step debugger meant for novices. You can put in code on the [edit](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) page then click "Visualize Execution" to start it running.

Among other things, it supports:

- hiding variables, e.g. to hide a variable named `x`, put this at the end:

  ```
  #pythontutor_hide: x
  ```
- [saving/sharing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4q3UKdEFKE&list=PLzV58Zm8FuBL2WxxZKGZ6j1dH8NKb_HYI&index=4)
- a few other languages like Java, JS, Ruby, C, C++

However it also [doesn't support a lot of things](https://github.com/pythontutor-dev/pythontutor/blob/master/unsupported-features.md), for example:

- Reading/writing files - use [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) and [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) instead: [demo](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=%23%20open%28%29%20is%20not%20supported%20in%20Online%20Python%20Tutor,%0A%23%20so%20use%20io.StringIO%20to%20simulate%20a%20file%20%28in%20Python%203%29%0Aimport%20io%0A%0A%23%20create%20a%20multi-line%20string%20and%20pass%20it%20into%20StringIO%0Af%20%3D%20io.StringIO%28%27%27%27first%20line%0Asecond%20line%0Athird%0Afourth%0Afifth%27%27%27%29%0A%0A%23%20now%20work%20with%20f%20as%20though%20it%20were%20an%20opened%20file%0Afor%20line%20in%20f%3A%0A%20%20%20%20line%20%3D%20line.strip%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20print%28line%29&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)
- Code that is too large, runs too long, or defines too many variables or objects
- Command-line arguments
- Lots of standard library modules like argparse, csv, enum, html, os, sys, weakref...
- Python 3.7+

Answer (score 5):

### Let's take look at what `breakpoint()` can do for you in 3.7+.

I have installed [ipdb](https://pypi.org/project/ipdb/) and [pdbpp](https://pypi.org/project/pdbpp/), which are both enhanced debuggers, via

```
pip install pdbpp
pip install ipdb
```

My test script, really doesn't do much, just calls `breakpoint()`.

```
#test_188_breakpoint.py
myvars=dict(foo="bar")
print("before breakpoint()")
breakpoint()   # 
print(f"after breakpoint myvars={myvars}")
```

breakpoint() is linked to the [PYTHONBREAKPOINT](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONBREAKPOINT) environment variable.

#### CASE 1:  disabling breakpoint()

You can set the variable via `bash` as usual

`export PYTHONBREAKPOINT=0`

This turns off breakpoint() where it does nothing (as long as you haven't modified `sys.breakpointhook()` which is outside of the scope of this answer).

This is what a run of the program looks like:

```
(venv38) myuser@explore$ export PYTHONBREAKPOINT=0
(venv38) myuser@explore$ python test_188_breakpoint.py
before breakpoint()
after breakpoint myvars={'foo': 'bar'}
(venv38) myuser@explore$
```

Didn't stop, because I disabled breakpoint.  Something that `pdb.set_trace()` can't do !

#### CASE 2:  using the default pdb behavior:

Now, let's unset `PYTHONBREAKPOINT` which puts us back to normal, enabled-breakpoint behavior (it's only disabled when `0` not when empty).

```
(venv38) myuser@explore$ unset PYTHONBREAKPOINT
(venv38) myuser@explore$ python test_188_breakpoint.py
before breakpoint()
[0] > /Users/myuser/kds2/wk/explore/test_188_breakpoint.py(6)<module>()
-> print(f"after breakpoint myvars={myvars}")
(Pdb++) print("pdbpp replaces pdb because it was installed")
pdbpp replaces pdb because it was installed
(Pdb++) c
after breakpoint myvars={'foo': 'bar'}
```

It stopped, but I actually got `pdbpp` because it replaces `pdb` entirely while installed. If I unistalled `pdbpp`, I'd be back to normal `pdb`.

Note:  a standard `pdb.set_trace()` would still get me `pdbpp`

#### CASE 3: calling a custom debugger

But let's call `ipdb` instead.  This time, instead of setting the environment variable, we can use `bash` to set it only for this one command.

```
(venv38) myuser@explore$ PYTHONBREAKPOINT=ipdb.set_trace py test_188_breakpoint.py
before breakpoint()
> /Users/myuser/kds2/wk/explore/test_188_breakpoint.py(6)<module>()
      5 breakpoint()
----> 6 print(f"after breakpoint myvars={myvars}")
      7

ipdb> print("and now I invoked ipdb instead")
and now I invoked ipdb instead
ipdb> c
after breakpoint myvars={'foo': 'bar'}
```

Essentially, what it does, when looking at $PYTHONBREAKPOINT:

```
from ipdb import set_trace  # function imported on the right-most `.`
set_trace()
```

Again, much cleverer than a plain old pdb.set_trace()

#### in practice?  I'd probably settle on a debugger.

Say I want ipdb always, I would:

- `export` it via `.profile` or similar.
- disable on a command by command basis, without modifying the normal value

Example (`pytest` and debuggers often make for unhappy couples):

```
(venv38) myuser@explore$ export PYTHONBREAKPOINT=ipdb.set_trace
(venv38) myuser@explore$ echo $PYTHONBREAKPOINT
ipdb.set_trace
(venv38) myuser@explore$ PYTHONBREAKPOINT=0 pytest test_188_breakpoint.py
=================================== test session starts ====================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.6, pytest-5.1.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/myuser/kds2/wk/explore
plugins: celery-4.4.7, cov-2.10.0
collected 0 items

================================== no tests ran in 0.03s ===================================
(venv38) myuser@explore$ echo $PYTHONBREAKPOINT
ipdb.set_trace
```

#### p.s.

I'm using `bash` under `macos`, any posix shell will behave substantially the same.  Windows, either powershell or DOS, may have different capabilities, especially around `PYTHONBREAKPOINT=<some value> <some command>` to set a environment variable only for one command.

Answer (score 3):

If you come from Java/C# background I guess your best bet would be to use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) with [Pydev](http://pydev.org/). This gives you a fully functional IDE with debugger built in. I use it with django as well.

Answer (score 3):

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools

pudb is a good drop-in replacement for pdb

Answer (score 3):

[PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is an IDE for Python that includes a debugger. Watch this YouTube video for an introduction on using it to step through code:

[PyCharm Tutorial - Debug python code using PyCharm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBPoInSOiOY) (the debugging starts at [6:34](https://youtu.be/BBPoInSOiOY?t=394))

[image: Screenshot]

Note: PyCharm is a commercial product, but the company does provide a free license to students and teachers, as well as a "lightweight" Community version that is free and open-source.

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically stepping and tracing through python code is possible too (and its easy!). Look at the [sys.settrace()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) documentation for more details. Also [here](http://pymotw.com/2/sys/tracing.html) is a tutorial to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio with PTVS could be an option for you: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OneOfMicrosoftsBestKeptSecretsPythonToolsForVisualStudioPTVS.aspx