# How can I make ipdb show more lines of context while debugging?

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

By default, during debugging in IPython, [ipdb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) shows one line above and one line below the current position in code.

Is there an easy way to make the area shown a bit bigger? I'd think it would be configurable, but haven't been able to find it.

Comment: How can one line of context be considered a sensible default? :-) Feature request: https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/147

Comment: All these years later, the default is 1 line of context.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

easy way to do this - 2022

- figure out where you're loading ipdb from
- `import ipdb`
- `print(ipdb.__file__)`
- open `__main__.py` from that folder
- search for `except (configparser.NoSectionError, configparser.NoOptionError):`
- below it is 3. Change that to your desired value

Why this is better than the proper way:

- I don't need to learn a new configuration language
- I don't need to create a new configfile
- I don't need to debug why my configfile isn't being picked up
- you never get tricked by file scoping/permissions/visibility since you are sure which ipdb module is being loaded (i.e. it covers virtualenvs too)
- I don't have to talk to upstream and try to convince them to adopt this default.

Comment: I found mine in a different file on Ubuntu 12.04 - /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py

Comment: editing bowels of dependency package with bare hands not the way you usually want to configure something..

Comment: I'm surprised this is marked as "2022". I added the relevant functionality to IPython several years ago. You don't have to edit anything or use configs (if you really don't want to add 1 line to `~/.ipdb`) - you have a command for it. Editing the debugger this way has no guarantee of working between the updates, and you are setting other users up for crashes that the maintainers will not want or be able to resolve. Your answer is actively harmful.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik I'd guess having to set envvars loses about 50% of new programmers. Having to respawn shell before it works, another 20%.  Is it possible to increase the default to 5 or 10? I don't think 1 line visible by default makes sense. Alternatively can it have a param so I can do ipdb.set_trace(10) as my default? I dislike having to mess with system level things to fix python.  i.e. i think default should be 10, and those who want the old behavior can set THAT manually. Is there demand for the old behavior, or is it just legacy?  Forgive me if I'm missing why 1 line is good.

Comment: @fastmultiplication The default is 3, and if it was up to me (and if I had the time), I'd change it to something smarter than "up to n lines", so that multiline statements are handled better, and the output of `where` does not take up 200 lines. But that is beside the point. If you don't like env vars, you can just put `context = 10` in `~/.ipdb` and that's it. If that's hard for the user, then editing source code shouldn't be even under consideration - especially since they'd have to do it every time they create a new venv. Editing installed packages manually is just _a bad practice_, period.

Comment: Scratch that, the default is actually 5 as per IPython code. I'm not sure where are you getting your 1 from, the 5 has been the default since something like the cretaceous period: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blame/e95b0cf4deb44ab5dd7a2779ed2086b33ac1e640/IPython/core/debugger.py#L207

Ipdb indeed _had_ 3, which seems to be a bug that has been corrected since: https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/commit/b866254f72b859ba67451106d1a592df44564825

Comment: Ah, thanks. For me, on a new system of WSL+ubuntu using python3, I get one line before and one after the current line as the default new system values.  I interpret this as "3" total, which is what I see in code, too, right now for my system python 3.8

Comment: Could be because `ipdb` has issues with reading the config - that's the last case where it uses 3.

Answer (score 49):

You can type `l` in ipdb to show a few more lines of the current context

and you can keep hitting `l` and it continue revealing more lines from the file

If you want to show more lines of context around the current line you can type `l` to get the current line. And then type `l curr_line - 10, curr_line + 10`. Say I was on line 50 and I wanted to see the surrounding 20 lines. I would type: `l 40,60` to see more.

As noted by @jrieke in a comment, you can also hit `ll` to get a bigger chunk of context. One nice thing about `ll` is it will print all the way back from the start of the current method (whereas consecutive `l`s reveal further lines below your breakpoint).

Comment: Adding to this: You can also enter `ll` to get more lines at once.

Comment: The question asks for this to be done by default, not through additional user action.

Comment: This does not affect the context shown upon other commands like (w)here or (n)ext.

Answer (score 24):

EDIT: this answer is a bit outdated, see @Błażej Michalik's answer instead.

---

You can get more context by doing:

```
ipdb.set_trace(context=21)
```

## Permanent context size

To permanently set context size, find the installation directory by doing

```
python -c 'import ipdb; print(ipdb)'
```

which will show you a `__init__.py` file.  Open that file and find the line (which may also be found in IPDB's `__main__.py`:

```
def set_trace(frame=None, context=3):
```

change the `3` to however many context lines you want.

Comment: ipdb v0.10.2 hasn't been released yet and I cannot find anything related to IPDB_CONTEXT_SIZE anywhere, not even on their github repository.

Comment: @gnebehay, you're right, thanks.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: There is a simple config file option for it thesedays. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

You can put the following line in [the config file](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb?tab=readme-ov-file#using-configuration-file) to make ipdb set it automatically:

```
context = 10
```

If you want to have a persistent setting based on your shell config, you can also use `IPDB_CONTEXT_SIZE` variable. Add the following to your `~/.bashrc` / `~/.zshrc` / etc.:

```
export IPDB_CONTEXT_SIZE=10
```

*Thanks to [N1ngu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11715259) for pointing this out.*

Keep in mind though, that this is implemented in `ipdb` itself, not in `IPython`, so while it will work when used with `ipdb.set_trace()`, it doesn't apply to the `%debug` magic.

Starting with IPython 7.21 you can also use `context` command in ipdb to change the number of backtrace lines shown:

```py
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
...
ipdb> context 10
ipdb> bt
```

[image: Screenshot of IPDB after the context command has been used]

Apart from that, there's also the old `context=` argument in `set_trace()`, which makes it possible to set it at the time of running the debugger:

```py
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace(context=10)
# or, if you've set PYTHONBREAKPOINT=ipdb.set_trace in your environment
breakpoint(context=10)
```

Comment: Wow, this works.  In combination with setting default interactive shell colors to NoColor, this makes default Win10 WSL ubuntu python3 usable!

Answer (score 3):

Edit: it was implemented: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66474153/895245

As a quick complement to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35883288/895245) this is the one liner that you generally want to add to the code you want to debug:

```
__import__('ipdb').set_trace(context=21)
```

You likely want to add a shortcut for that from your editor, e.g. for [Vim snipmat](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) I have:

```
snippet ipd
    __import__('ipdb').set_trace(context=21)
```

so I can type just `ipd<tab>` and it expands to the breakpoint. Then removing it is easy with `dd` since everything is contained in a single line.

Feature request for ipdb to increase the default `context` size: https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/147

Answer (score 2):

Here's a patch to permanently set context for your program:

(works across set_trace and post_mortem)

```py
def ipdb_patch(context = 11):
    import ipdb
    ipdbmain = ipdb.__main__
    def _init_pdb(context=context, commands=[]):
        try              : p = ipdbmain.debugger_cls(context=context)
        except TypeError : p = ipdbmain.debugger_cls()
        p.rcLines.extend(commands)
        return p
    def set_trace(frame=None, context=context):
        ipdbmain.wrap_sys_excepthook()
        if frame is None : frame = ipdbmain.sys._getframe().f_back
        p = ipdbmain._init_pdb(context).set_trace(frame)
        if p and hasattr(p, 'shell') : p.shell.restore_sys_module_state()
    ipdbmain._init_pdb = _init_pdb
    ipdb.set_trace = set_trace
    return ipdb
ipdb = ipdb_patch()
```

to add breakpoint() functionality simply add:

```py
import sys
sys.breakpointhook = ipdb.set_trace
```

With that all the following commands have the right context size:

```py
ipdb.set_trace()
breakpoint()
ipdb.post_mortem()
ipdb.pm()
%debug
```

It does not however work with this:

```py
In [1]: %run -d file.py
```

If you know how to adjust that, please feel free to drop in comments

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop execution in a running system, as others said, use:

```py
ipdb.set_trace(context=number_of_lines)
```

For running some function or an object's method modifying this context lines is a little bit tricky. The only way I found was:

```py
ipdb.__main__._init_pdb(context=number_of_lines).runcall(callable, *args, **kwargs)
```

In case it serves someone.

Answer (score -1):

Following the @erock618 way, in more recent ipdb versions you can use:

```
debugger_cls = ipdb.__main__._get_debugger_cls()
```