# How to see step by step execution of python script in terminal

Tags: python

I have python script

```
fruits.py
```

when I run it `python fruits.py`, it generates output.

Is there a way like some debug flag in python? or some code to write in script, with which I can see code execution step by step in terminal.

Comment: do you mean pdb? https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/can-you-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues

Comment: no this is not what I am looking for. I want my code to show all execution steps one by one while it is executing in terminal instead of just showing me the output.

Comment: @geek_xed, that is pretty much what a debugger does