# How can I start pdb for Python 3.6 on Windows?

Tags: python, pdb

Per the accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/can-you-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues), I'm trying to use `pdb` for debugging.

I can start the debugger successfully with this syntax:

```
python -m pdb program.py
```

but prefer the other option provided in the answer (which isn't working):

```
pdb program.py
```

Is the second syntax supported on Windows? If so, how can I get it working? The error is the standard "not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: You could create a batch file called `pdb` that'd run `python -m pdb <arguments passed to the batch file>`.

Comment: Thanks. Is the `pdb program.py` syntax not supported then?

Comment: well, it gives you an error. Maybe there are some prerequisites for this to run properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not working because you don't have an association of `.py` with the Python executable.

The file `pdb.py` is in your global packages directory (which is why `python -m pdb` is able to find it), unfortunately when you do `pdb program.py` Windows is doing the following:

1. Searches the directory that you ran the command in for a file called `pdb.{com|bat|exe}` and whatever else is identified in [`PATHEXT`](http://environmentvariables.org/PathExt); if not, then it checks the file associations (you can list these by typing `FTYPE`) for executables to run for a specific file extension.
2. Repeats #1 for each directory that is part of `PATH`

On your system, you have not associated the `.py` extension with any executable, thus Python doesn't know how to run the file.

To make your life easier, just use the `python3 -m pdb` syntax; not only will it work, it is also more portable across platforms.

Comment: Thanks. You were exactly right! I was able to get things working by adding `.py` to the `PATHEXT` variable. However, I think I'll use the syntax you suggest since it works without any additional setup.