# Include PDB by default in all python files

Tags: python, pdb

I need pdb in almost all of my python files. Is there any way by which I can get rid of the pain of writing import pdb in every python file I create.

In other words, Is there any way I can just write pdb.set_trace() and can run the program. Something like including pdb in core python libraries,or making an alias for command python etc.

Comment: What about writing `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in one line where ever you need it?

Comment: In the case of an executable script, you only need it in the script

Comment: @akhilsp This is my current method. I have made key bindings for inserting this in vim. But I wanted to know if an easier method exist.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, as of Python 3.7 just write `breakpoint()` which is a builtin, with some [enhanced capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52040841) as well.