# How do you use pdb in Hydrogen?

Tags: python, pdb, hydrogen

I am new to debugging in Python, and I currently use Hydrogen within Atom to do most of my Python work. I have looked into debugging, and it seems that the Python package [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) is the standard way to debug in Python. Most of the examples I can find seem to require using a command line on a `.py` file. However, in Hydrogen I would want to run it within the kernel on individual lines of the code, since I don't think `pdb` will work on a markdown (`.md`) file. Is there a way I can debug within my workflow, or do I need to make `.py` files of my code and run `pdb` on them?

Answer (score 0):

I had read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37903700/4521071) and tried to implement "C. From Within Your Program". It had thrown errors, and I gave up. However, I went to [the source](https://pymotw.com/2/pdb/) that the answer had cited, and used this code:

```
import pdb

class MyObj(object):

    def __init__(self, num_loops):
        self.count = num_loops

    def go(self):
        for i in range(self.count):
            pdb.set_trace()
            print(i)
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyObj(5).go()
```

From this, I was able to get `pdb` to run in Hydrogen.