# how to debug local variables in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

i'd like to print the value of tensor in tensorflow,but it falied,how can i correct it?

```
train_vector1, train_vector2, train_vector3, train_vector4, train_vector5,train_labels = decode_records(FLAGS.record_train, FLAGS.epoch, record_params)
sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)
print(sess.run(train_labels))
```

and run the tf.py,the progress is hunted.why?

```
2018-06-15 16:52:53.782143: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-06-15 16:52:54.111552: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB major: 6 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.3285
pciBusID: 0000:0d:00.0
totalMemory: 15.89GiB freeMemory: 15.60GiB
2018-06-15 16:52:54.111607: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1312] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-06-15 16:52:54.408837: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 15128 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:0d:00.0, compute capability: 6.0)
```

Comment: How about using some IDE like PyCharm to debug your code?

Comment: is there any other way to debug directly by shell?

Comment: Maybe this will answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/can-you-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues