# Why am I not getting an output for the following python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not getting any output from interpreter **after I input a value**.

Here's my code:

```
number = int(input("Enter the number to test:"))
count = 0
if number % 2 == 0:
        while number > 1:
            number /= 2
            count += 1
else:
    while number > 1:
        number = (3 * number) + 1
        count += 1

print("Iteration count: " + count)
```

**Expected output is 15 for input = 11**

**Edit:** The Collatz Conjecture (above) use the following algorithm: If n is even, divide it by 2, else multiply by 3 and add 1. Start over until you get 1.

Comment: Because `number` will always be greater than 1 when odd, and you entered an infinite loop

Comment: You need to move the even/odd test *inside* the loop.  As it stands, look what happens if it's odd:  It just keeps tripling it and adding 1 forever, since it will remain > 1`.  Also, change `number /= 2` to `number //= 2`, otherwise it will be converted to floating point.

Comment: `number = (3 * number) + 1` will continue to increase the value, so `while number > 1:` will always be True. As Fedrico pointed out.

Comment: Because `number = (3 * number) + 1` will go infinite.. `number` will never be less than one. So, while loops never end.

Comment: "If n is even, divide it by 2, else multiply by 3 and add 1. Start over until you get 1." - this is not what your code does. You should put the if statements into the loop. As of now, your algorithm doesn't have anything to do with the Collatz conjecture

Comment: Search SO for python + collatz - you can find working examples and compare them to what you got - yours is not quite right.

Comment: You might also want to read through [how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues) or  [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) which will teach you about debugging - the best skill to learn as someone trying to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created an infinite loop in your while statements. A good way you can check this yourself is to print `number` inside the while loop, and you will quickly see where you are going wrong.

I don't want to give away the solution as this sounds too much like homework - but you must ensure your while loop condition is met, or it will never exit.

Comment: This only partially addresses the problems.  The other problem, which I pointed out, is that `number` is being converted to floating point by the divide-by-two operator.  The `/=` operator is incorrect.  It needs to be `//=` in Python 3.  It might work as floating point, but it clearly isn't desirable.