# Make Python shell show commands as they are done

Tags: python

How do I make the python shell print/show the commands that is done exactly when its done?

For an example is,
If my python file contains:

```
variable = something
IF variable == something:
    print “hello”
```

So when I run the file in python shell, I want it to print all the commands as they are executed.

Comment: a debugger will highlight the code for you at runtime.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack! Like @MJanaTil suggested, you could use a line debugger to step through your code line by line. For example, Python comes with pdb as an in-built debugger. A somewhat intuitive tutorial for pdb is provided by DigitalOcean here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-python-debugger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in [trace module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/trace.html)

```
python3 -m trace --trace file.py
```