# How do I see how my program is executed line by line

Tags: python, line-by-line

I am trying to learn the basics of programming using python, and I am getting to the point where I have to deal with if statements and for loops. The thing is that I am getting a bit confused as to how my code is running. Is there a way to see how my code is being executed line by line; I feel that  that would deepen my understanding of why code has to be written a certain way in order for computers to understand what I am trying to accomplish. I dont know if my question makes any sense to you guys, but I hope you can help me. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Use a debugger or an editor/IDE that comes with one.

Comment: You can also accept which answer you found best.

Comment: Pycharm is a great choice, they have an excellent debugger and great code completion. As a beginner, it will help you muchly;  https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interactive debugger. Some Python IDEs provide it.

You may want to give VS Code a try. Take a look at the [debugger part of the tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_configure-and-run-the-debugger).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a debugger. You can find some online, for example here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_debugger . Alternatively you can use pdb, the python debugger (the above link is just a friendly wrapper around it), directly from the command line, but if you are new to python and programming I wouldn't recommand it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pdb`.

```
python -m pdb script.py
```

More information on [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues).

`pdb` documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).