# Hiding Label from on one Class by pressing a Button in another Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter

I have an idea to create a simple scoreboard app (sport) with two windows (creating in Tkinter). One is for controlling and another one for output information.

So the idea is that I press button "show scoreboard" in a tk.Toplevel window and it appears in the main app window. And as I press hide, it hides. I know that I can create it just writing script without Classes and just like hundreds def strings but I want to use OOP as I would like to start programming the right way.

My problem is that when I press "Hide the scoreboard" (I create Labels for scoreboard) label is not hiding. Any suggestions?

I know that commands and defs must be in the same "tree", but how to arrange it when using the OOP.

So here is my code

```
import tkinter as tk

def forget():
scoreboard.pack_forget()

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Scorebug")
        self.geometry("500x300")
        self.configure(background="green")
        scoreboard = tk.Label(self, text="This is like scoreboard")
        scoreboard.pack()

class Control(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Controls")
        self.geometry("100x300")
        self.configure(background="red")

        hidelabels = tk.Button(self, text="Hide the scoreboard", command=forget)
        hidelabels.pack()


app = Main()
ctr = Control()

ctr.mainloop()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: a good thing to learn is how to use the debugger, good answers for debugger here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues. As a first step see if you can use the debugger to check the line  hidelabels = tk.Button ... is actually being invoked when you run the code

Comment: `tkinter` should run only one `mainloop()`

Comment: your `scoreboard` is local variable and exists only when Python runs `__Init__` but later it removes this variable. You should use `self.` to keep access to `self.scoreboard.` You can send main window to second window as parameter - `Control(app)` and then you have access to main window,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should use `self.scoreboard` to have access from other places.

```
self.scoreboard = tk.Label(self, text="This is like scoreboard")
self.scoreboard.pack()
```

and now you can remove it using

```
command=app.scoreboard.pack_forget
```

You can also send main window as argument to second window

```
ctr = Control(app)

class Control(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
```

and then you can bind

```
command=parent.scoreboard.pack_forget
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Scorebug")
        self.geometry("500x300")
        self.configure(background="green")
        self.scoreboard = tk.Label(self, text="This is like scoreboard")
        self.scoreboard.pack()

class Control(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Controls")
        self.geometry("100x300")
        self.configure(background="red")

        hidelabels = tk.Button(self, text="Hide the scoreboard", command=parent.scoreboard.pack_forget)
        hidelabels.pack()


app = Main()
ctr = Control(app)
app.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** You can also send only `scireboard`  as argument to second window

```
ctr = Control(app.scoreboard)
```

and then you can bind

```
command=parent.pack_forget
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This is what I needed. I broke my head trying to find out what I am  doing wrong. I'm learning python for a month or so I'm a newbie.