# Value Error : could not convert string to float: 'Male'

Tags: python

**My code:**

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

BMI = pd.read_csv('c://500_Person_Gender_Height_Weight_Index.csv')

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(BMI, BMI.gender_lbl, test_size=0.3,random_state=42) 


from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

gnb = GaussianNB()

gnb.fit(X_train, y_train) --> shows error

y_pred = gnb.predict(X_test)
y_pred
```

I am not sure of what to do here.
If anyone could help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Isn't error message you got self explanatory?

Comment: Had the OP been able to understand that, things would be better!

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments said, you are trying to convert a string or object (in this case "Male") into a float.

Try to output your variables and their types to makes you see where you are trying to convert the float.

Like described in the error and in the documentation :

> Raised when an operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value [...]  [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError)

For further debugging tricks, you can consult this thread :
[How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues)

Otherwise, some debugger (like PyCharm) can help you by inserting breakpoints and getting values of active variables

Comment: Could you show me the coding to help with that because I am not sure how to convert to float