# I have just started learning super basic Python this week. Look at my basic code for entry ticket in a park

Tags: python

Ticket price depends on age. I am getting an error "invalid literal for value with base 10" in the line

```
age=int(age)
```

What does this error mean and how can I solve it? please fix  indentation error
(if any)

```
name="\t\n\n WHAT IS YOUR NAME?\t\n\t\t\t"
input(name)
name=str(name)
gender = "\nWhat is your GENDER (M/F) \t\n\t\t\t"
input(gender)
gender=str(gender)
age = "\t\n\tWhat is your age\t\n\t\t\t"
input(age)
age= int(age)
if gender == 'm ':
 gd="Mr. "
elif gender == 'f':
gd="Ms. "
else :
  gd = "_"

price = ['free for kid $0' , '$ 10' , '$15']
if age<=3:
  print("Hello  " + gd + name.title() + "  your Ticket fee is  " + price[0])
elif age <= 12:
  print("Hello "+gd+ name.title() + "  your Ticket fee is  " + price[1])
else:
 print("Hello "+gd+ name.title() + "  your Ticket fee is  " + price[2])
```

Comment: What's the value you're giving as input for `age`?

Comment: any number like 20 40 78...

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity for you to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Set a breakpoint in this line `age= int(age)` and check the value of `age`. You will be surprised.

Comment: If you don't know what "breakpoint" means read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Comment: And then this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i am also new in Python but as i understand

```
1- age = "\t\n\tWhat is your age\t\n\t\t\t"
2- input(age)
3- age= int(age)
```

you can change as below

```
age = int(input("\t\n\tWhat is your age\t\n\t\t\t"))
```

1. line means age is a string which containt this data
2. read console and set to age variable
3. try to convert to int and set as same variable

string can carry multi type variable so should be carryfully.

BTW:

1. for gender 'f' and 'F' is different for python you can add OR condition.
2. try and catch is good for converting data

Comment: how to make inputs 'f and F " act same

Comment: if gender == 'm ' or gender=='M':

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong from the basics.
input is the keyword that takes the input from the user as well as shows the input message to the user. You need to store the value to a variable.

So your code should be like that,

```
name_prompet = "\t\n\n WHAT IS YOUR NAME?\t\n\t\t\t"
name = input(name_prompet)
```

same it should be with the age,

```
age_prompet = "\t\n\tWhat is your age\t\n\t\t\t"
age = input(age)
```

SO at age = int(age) technically you are trying to convert a string into int that's why it's an error.

Tell me if you need anything else.

Comment: what should i do so that this program asking name gender and age should continue without ending at "Hello Mr XYZ your ticket fee is **"

Comment: you can use a while loop for that purpose.