# Need function explanation for Towers of Hanoi

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently following a course and we were given to write a function for the Towers of Hanoi mathematical puzzle.

After following up some videos on youtube about it, I have compiled the following function:

```
def hanoi(n , source, target, spare):
    if n == 1:
        print("Move disk 1 from", source, "to", target)
    else:
        hanoi(n-1, source, spare, target)
        print ("Move disk", n, "from", source, "to", target)
        hanoi(n-1, spare, target, source)
```

Let's say I call this function as `hanoi(3, "source", "target", "spare")`

The output that I get is:

```
Move disk 1 from source to target
Move disk 2 from source to spare
Move disk 1 from target to spare
Move disk 3 from source to target
Move disk 1 from spare to source
Move disk 2 from spare to target
Move disk 1 from source to target
```

A friend recommended me to write down the code on paper in order to understand it but I fail to understand:

- why is the function running the `if` clause when my **n** equals 3?
- how is the computer actually running the program? What is the logic of going through the conditional statements?
  This baffles me also due to the fact that I put that `print` statement in between (because placing it in another place wouldn't have printed the right results)

Thanks a lot for your help and time!

EDIT: The Towers of Hanoi means having (by default) 3 poles. One pole would be the `source` pole (where the **n** disks would be originally placed), 2nd pole is the `spare` pole used as a helper and the 3rd pole is the `target` pole (where all the **n** disks would be originally placed). I used these variables to represent the poles and to be able to show the movement of the disks

The rules are: you can move 1 disk at a time and you cannot place a bigger disk on a smaller disk.

Comment: It would help a lot if you told what the variables `n , source, target, spare` mean.

Comment: editing in the original post in a bit

Comment: Why do you think that the `if` clause is run when `n` equals 3?

Comment: `why is the function running the if clause when my n equals 3?` it doesn't, it goes to `else` and runs `hanoi(3-1, source, spare, target)`. - then the new inner thing enters `else` as well, and runs `hanoi` with n=2-1. only then the thing is printed. - then the innermost call ends. so we get back to n=2 and it prints. then it runs n=2-1 hanoi again... and so on. "A friend recommended me to write down the code on paper in order to understand it but I fail to understand" - do what I did and analyse where it goes "down" and with what values. and when it goes back "up".

Comment: actually, if you trace it through (which I highly recommend: try pretending you're the Python interpreter and stepping through this one line at a time), the `print` statement in the `if` *is* the first one that gets executed. That's not because `3` passes the `n == 1` check, but because the `else` clause starts with the recursive call, so we go down the callstack to the `n = 1` case before anything else gets printed.

Comment: @mkrieger1 because the first line of the output is the command which is in the ``ìf``` clause

Comment: Why don't you just print `n` as well to see what's happening?

Comment: As others suggested, try to follow the order of the calls, pretending you're the python interpreter, even if the first print statement is from evaluating the `if` clause to `True`, it only does that after several calls to `hanoi`. Remember that this is a recursive function :)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I printed ```n``` in different positions inside the ```hanoi``` and the only thing that made sense was to print it like this:

```
def hanoi(n , source, target, spare):
    if n == 1:
        print("Move diskkk 1 from", source, "to", target)
    else:
        hanoi(n-1, source, spare, target)
        print ("Move disssk", n, "from", source, "to", target)
        print(n)
        hanoi(n-1, spare, target, source)
```
After this, I was getting the ```n``` printed after the 2nd movement of the disks. Not sure what to follow in here

Comment: @h4z3 so that it is actually doing after running the 1st line from the ```else``` is to print the statement for ```hanoi(3-1, source, spare, target)``` and then go to the 3rd line in the ```else``` clause and run ```hanoi(n-1, spare, target, source)```?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues)

Comment: @ValentinDS it doesn't jump. each call `hanoi(...)` will enter the function with new values. it's basically as if you pasted `hanoi` code in the place of the call. The inner call starts from first line and checks the ifs again. and so on. When you exit the inner call, you return to where it was called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the comments are too short to explain it clearly.

Each function call starts the function from its first line.
And after the function ends, the code goes back to where it got invoked.

> A friend recommended me to write down the code on paper in order to understand it

That's what we're gonna do here. Analyse the code line-by-line and see when it goes deeper and when it leaves.

- `hanoi(3, "source", "target", "spare")` This will go to the `else`. And run `hanoi` with n=2

  - So n=2, right? So we enter `else` again. And run `hanoi` *again* but with n=1

    - we go deeper! Now n=1, so we finally hit `print`! That's where `Move disk 1 from to target` came from! The function **exits**.
  - We *get back to where it was called*. We did first `hanoi` in `else`. Now we hit another `print`. That's where `Move disk 2 from source to spare` comes from.
  - We get to the next line. We run `hanoi` with n=1 again.

    - We're inside again. n=1, so we get into `if` and print `Move disk 1 from target to spare` and exit
  - We got to where we invoked it (so we're in n=2 level) but we don't have any more lines to run. We exit
- We're back to the top level. Now we hit the print `Move disk 3 from source to target`
- Next line. Another call to `hanoi`, with n=2

  - n=2, again: else, go deeper

    - n=1, print, exit
  - we went back, so we print
  - and go deeper again

    - n=1, print, exit
  - exit
- exit

---

To understand recursion, you can actually do debug printing when entering and leaving.

```
def hanoi(n , source, target, spare):
    print(f"   DEBUG: Starting hanoi({n}, {source}, {target}, {spare})")
    if n == 1:
        print("Move disk 1 from", source, "to", target)
    else:
        hanoi(n-1, source, spare, target)
        print ("Move disk", n, "from", source, "to", target)
        hanoi(n-1, spare, target, source)
    print(f"   DEBUG: Exiting hanoi({n}, {source}, {target}, {spare})")
```

```
>>> hanoi(3, "src", "trg", "spr")
   DEBUG: Starting hanoi(3, src, trg, spr)
   DEBUG: Starting hanoi(2, src, spr, trg)
   DEBUG: Starting hanoi(1, src, trg, spr)
Move disk 1 from src to trg
   DEBUG: Exiting hanoi(1, src, trg, spr)
Move disk 2 from src to spr
   DEBUG: Starting hanoi(1, trg, spr, src)
Move disk 1 from trg to spr
   DEBUG: Exiting hanoi(1, trg, spr, src)
   DEBUG: Exiting hanoi(2, src, spr, trg)
Move disk 3 from src to trg
   DEBUG: Starting hanoi(2, spr, trg, src)
   DEBUG: Starting hanoi(1, spr, src, trg)
Move disk 1 from spr to src
   DEBUG: Exiting hanoi(1, spr, src, trg)
Move disk 2 from spr to trg
   DEBUG: Starting hanoi(1, src, trg, spr)
Move disk 1 from src to trg
   DEBUG: Exiting hanoi(1, src, trg, spr)
   DEBUG: Exiting hanoi(2, spr, trg, src)
   DEBUG: Exiting hanoi(3, src, trg, spr)
```

See how the added print lines line up with what I wrote.

Comment: Yess, this is it. I also wrote it on the paper and I got it finally. And now reading your post makes even more sense. All along this time I was missing the idea of the recursion: calling a function within itself and when that happens, the function takes it again from the start.