# List is becoming None type in python

Tags: python

The program is for hangman with hints (MIT OCW 6.0001 ps 2 ). It is supposed to check whether the word I have guessed up to now (here my_word "a_ple") can be the word chosen by the game (other_word). Hence in "a_ple" and "apple", since I have already guessed "p" but I still have the position with index[1] as a "_" it means that the word cannot be apple and the output printed should be false

```
 my_word="a_ple"
other_word = "apple"
import string

def match_with_gaps(my_word, other_word):

    matching = False
    alphabet="string.ascii_lowercase"
    alphabet=list(alphabet)
    
    if len(my_word) == len(other_word):
        
        for i in range(len(my_word)):
            if my_word[i] != "_":
                for a in range(len(other_word)):
                    
                    if my_word[i] == other_word[a]:
                        if my_word[a] != "_":
                            print(type(alphabet)) #to check error in alphabet
                            if my_word[i] in alphabet:
                            
                                matching = True
                            else:
                                break
                        else:
                            break
                alphabet = alphabet.remove(my_word[i])                  

    return matching

print(match_with_gaps(my_word, other_word))
```

Output :
I get one output as class list and then in the second iteration I get "can't perform remove on NoneType"

I am not understanding at which step is my alphabet list becoming None Type.
I tried using a clone of alphabet but it was yielding the same outcome

Comment: ``alphabet.remove(my_word[i])`` is an inplace operation. It returns ``None`` – do not assign it back to ``alphabet``.

Comment: *I am not understanding at which step is my alphabet list becoming None* - you could have found out by printing it after every step or using a debugger.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi okay so i made it like if ```word[i] in alphabet_clone     alphabet_clone=alphabet.remove(word[i])``` but now it says x is not in list

Comment: @mkrieger1 i tried printing it after every step but Im not understanding where should i put the print command. ill try the debugger thing

Comment: See: [link 1](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues)

Comment: @ShauryaGoyal *Do not assign the result of ``list.remove``!* It doesn't matter what you assign it to, it will always be ``None``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I got it now thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
alphabet = alphabet.remove(my_word[i])
```

remove has no return (it's an inplace function as MisterMiyagi mentioned), see:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

so if you assign x = foo.remove("foo"), x will be None. Don't use the return of remove().