# Bagels test project issues, it's all Bagels

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying out the Bagels Pico Fermi game, but I'm trying to write the code without looking to learn.

https://inventwithpython.com/bigbookpython/project1.html

I've written and rewritten this code at least 10 times, and as far as I can tell, the logic makes sense. However, whenever running the code and guessing, I either get all "Bagels" or one Fermi and 2 Bagels.

I am VERY new to python, so I am not really sure what to look up to fix this without just directly copying the working code from the sample.

```
print('Welcome to Bagels! The Deductive Logic Game!')

print('''The rules are simple,
Pico: The digit is correct but in the wrong position.
Fermi: The digit is correct and in the right position.
Bagels: The digit is not correct.
''')

print('You have 10 guesses to guess the secret 3 digit number, what is your first guess?')

import random

secretint = random.randint(1, 999)
secret = str(secretint).zfill(3)
print(secret)

guesses = 0
while guesses <= 10:
    guess = str(input())
    # guess is equal to secret
    if guess == secret:
        print('VICTORY')
        exit()
    else:

        guesses += 1
        digit1 = secret[:1]
        digit2 = secret[:2]
        digit3 = secret[:3]
        guess1 = guess[:1]
        guess2 = guess[:2]
        guess3 = guess[:3]

        if guess1 != digit1 and (guess1 == (digit2 or digit3)):
            print('Pico')
        else:
            if guess1 == digit1:
                print('Fermi')
            else:
                print('Bagels')

        if guess2 != digit2 and (guess2 == (digit1 or digit3)):
            print('Pico')
        else:
            if guess2 == digit2:
                print('Fermi')
            else:
                print('Bagels')

        if guess3 != digit3 and (guess3 == (digit1 or digit2)):
            print('Pico')
        else:
            if guess3 == digit3:
                print('Fermi')
            else:
                print('Bagels')

if guesses <= 11:
    print('Out of guesses, goodbye!')
```

Comment: `guess1 == (digit2 or digit2)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: `digit2 = digit[:2]` and `digit3 = digit[:3]` also does not do what you think it does.

Comment: You should read the great articles [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/).

Comment: As well as [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues)

Comment: I will look into this thank you.