# I am trying to write a function swap(x, i, j) that returns a version of the string x with the characters at indices i and j swapped

Tags: python, string

I am new to strings and I have am trying to swap characters based on their indices

If either index is invalid (i.e., something
besides 0, 1, 2, ... , len(x) - 1), the function should return None.

```
x =0
i = 0
j = 0


def swap(x, i, j):
    x = (input("Enter a string: "))
    i = int(input("first number swap: "))
    j = int(input("Second number swapped: "))
    for ch in range(i, j):
        print(x[i:j])
    if ch not in range(i, j):
        print("None")



swap(x, i, j)
```

I tried using this function but I get a repeat based on input j, minus the letters excluded based on input i

```
#input for x = sloth
#input for i = 4
#input for j = 1 
#will equal = lot x3
```

Instead I want the character at index 4 to be switched with character at index 1, but if it is not in the range of those characters, then the program should return 'none'

can anyone show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are not doing any swapping here.  You shouldn't be checking `ch`, you should be checking that `i` and `j` are within `range(len(x))`.  You should not be doing the inputs as part of the function.  Your function accepts `x`, `i`, and `j` as parameters.  Do the inputs outside the function, and pass the values in.  And your `for`/`print` loop does exactly what you say.  It prints the selected part of the string once for each number in the range.

Comment: [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues)
 If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features  Or the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening. 
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
x = input('Enter your string: ')
i = int(input('Enter the index of the first letter: '))
j = int(input('Enter the 2nd index of the next letter: ')  

def swap(x, i, j):
i, j = sorted((i, j))
if i and j in range(len(x)):
    return x[:i] + x[j] + x[i+1:j] + x[i] + x[j+1:]
else:
    return None
```

Use `len()` in the range in order to determine how many indexes are present in the input. Use i and j in an `if` statement along with the range in order to fix the range. Finally, use `return` along with the statement that swaps the input i and j.

Comment: This has a bug.  Try `swap("foo", 10, 1)`.

Comment: (the mild awkwardness of handling this correctly is why I used `try/except` instead in my answer that you mostly copied this from...)

Answer (score 2):

If the function is supposed to take `x`, `i`, and `j` as arguments, you should use those arguments, not call `input()` inside the function.  If you want to use `input()` to get the arguments, do that before you call the function.

Since strings are immutable, you can't simply swap the characters, so I suggest building a new string via slicing:

```
def swap(x, i, j):
    i, j = sorted((i, j))
    try:
        return x[:i] + x[j] + x[i+1:j] + x[i] + x[j+1:]
    except IndexError:
        return None

print(swap(
    input("Enter a string: "),
    int(input("first number swap: ")),
    int(input("Second number swapped: "))
))
```

```
Enter a string: abcdefg
first number swap: 2
Second number swapped: 4
abedcfg
```

Another option might be to convert `x` to a mutable sequence (like a `list`) so you can do the swap, and then `join` it back into a string to return it:

```
def swap(x, i, j):
    y = list(x)
    try:
        y[i], y[j] = y[j], y[i]
        return ''.join(y)
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

Comment: what about using `len()` and `range()`  only?

Comment: You can't solve it using *only* those functions, since you need some way to access the elements of the string at specific indices.

Comment: I was asking because I was told that the only built-in functions that had to be included were the `len()` and `range()` functions, which was why I was messing up.