# For loop - I can only enter 1 integer

Tags: python, for-loop, integer, python-2.x

I am unable to enter more than one integer. I should be able to specify how many and then input like so...

```
How many integers? 3
Please enter an integer 1: 5
Please enter an integer 2: 2
Please enter an integer 3: 6
Using a for loop
5
2
6
```

However I am only being asked for integer 1 (in a continuous loop)

Below is the code:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sys

target_int = raw_input("How many integers?")

try:
  target_int = int(target_int)
except ValueError:
  sys.exit("You must enter an integer")

ints = list()

count = 0

while count < target_int:
 new_int = raw_input("Please enter integer {0}:".format(count + 1))
 isint = False
 try:
   new_int = int(new_int)

 except:
   print("You must enter an integer")

 if isint == True:
     ints.append(new_int)
     count += 1

print("Using a for loop")
for value in ints:
  print(str(value))
~
```

Comment: Set `isint = True` after typecast attempt in try clause

Comment: [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues)
 If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features  Or the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening. 
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Delete all lines *using* `isint`; then move `ints.append(new_int); count += 1` to the try suite.

Comment: don't use bare except. change it with `except ValueError`

Comment: Thank you, all. I use Pycharm at work (currently learning Python) and have used step through to debug. This time I just fired up my laptop and started editting in VIM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is as noted, that you aren't setting `isint`. But you shouldn't anyway, as you already cast in the `try` block. So if you reach this code, it is necessarily an `int`. 2 other small things are, I'm running in Python 3, since it was released 14 years ago, so `raw_input` is `input`, and it is good to get into the habit of initializing lists with `[]` instead of `list()`. It is faster sometimes, and never slower.

Here is working code:

```py
import sys

target_int = input("How many integers?")

try:
    target_int = int(target_int)
except ValueError:
    sys.exit("You must enter an integer")

ints = []

count = 0

while count < target_int:
    new_int = input("Please enter integer {0}:".format(count + 1))
    try:
        new_int = int(new_int)
    except ValueError:
        print("You must enter an integer")
        continue # so it doesn't try to append

    # No need to check isint. It is.
    ints.append(new_int)
    count += 1

print("Using a for loop")
for value in ints:
    print(str(value))
```

Another small improvement is to avoid `count` altogether, since it is always the length of `ints` already.

```py
import sys

target_int = input("How many integers?")

try:
    target_int = int(target_int)
except ValueError:
    sys.exit("You must enter an integer")

ints = []

while len(ints) < target_int:
    new_int = input("Please enter integer {0}:".format(len(ints) + 1))
    try:
        ints.append(int(new_int))
    except ValueError:
        print("You must enter an integer")


print("Using a for loop")
for value in ints:
    print(str(value))
```

Comment: Thank you! I am still in my infancy with programming and wish to adopt good habits!