# match case can't access attribute

Tags: python

In the following code, I defined `self.dir` in the match case

```
class Enemies(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):

        self.image = pygame.image.load("picture.png").convert_alpha()
        self.seat = random.choices(
            (range(1, 13)), weights=(1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3))

        match self.seat:
            case 1:
                self.dir = 315
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect(bottomright=(0, 0))
                # there are many more cases but they are similar

        print(self.dir)
```

When I run the code, in the `print(self.dir)` part, it returned an AttributeError. But I defined `self.dir` in the match case. Do you think it is match case's problem or am I missing something?

Edit: it's not the match case's problem. random.choices() returns a list and in the match case, it needs an int.

Comment: When you printed something *within* each `case` statement what happened?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues). [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences) returns a list, not an integer. Maybe use `random.choice` instead.

Comment: @wwii I tried random.choices(usual thing)[0] and it worked. If I want to use random.choice, I cannot have weighted results tho. should I just stick with random.choices()[0] ?

Comment: .. stay with `random.choices()[0]` if you need them to be weighted. Or try `self.seat,*_ = random.choices(...`. Or `[self.seat] = random.choices(...`.

Answer (score 0):

self.dir will only exist if the random is equal to 1. set this variable out of scope so that it always exists.

```
self.dir = None

match self.seat:
    case 1:
        self.dir = 315
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(bottomright=(0, 0))
        # there are many more cases but they are similar

print(self.dir)
```

Comment: While this will alleviate the `AttributeError` problem, it is not the *answer* - the match/case statements still won't work.

Comment: This is the answer to the issue title 'match case can't access attribute'. But thanks for the feedback. The variable type in match case can be solved in several ways.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did some testing after the post and there's nothing wrong with the match case. wwii pointed out that random.choices() returns a list and that is the problem.