# Web scrape return empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to build a web scrape for Trustpilot, however, the code keeps returning empty data frames, I really can't figure out why. Could someone please help me? Thank you so so
much. This is the output I get. I am a new beginner in Python, any help much appreciated.

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Title, Body, Rating, Date]
Index: []

```
code:
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import time

from time import sleep
from random import randint

#Not needed but I like a timer to see how long the code takes to run
then = time.time()

#Create empty lists to hold data
reviews = []
headings = []
stars = []
dates = []

#Set number of pages to scrape, you need to check on TrustPilot to see how many to scrape
#in this instance at the time of coding there were 287 pages to be scraped
# The first number 1 means start at 1, the number 287 means stop at 287
#the third number which is 1 means go from 1 to 287 in steps of 1
pages = np.arange(1, 10, 1)


#Create a loop to go over the reviews
for page in pages:
    page = requests.get("https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.dugood.org" + "?page=" + str(page))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
    #Set the tag we wish to start at, this is like a parent tag where we will go in and get everything below it`enter code here`
    review_div = soup.find_all('div', class_="review-content")


    #loop to iterate through each reviews
    for container in review_div:

        #Get the body of the review
        #If there is no review left by the user we will get a "-" returned by using 'if len(nv) == True else '-''
        #TrustPilot will add nothing if there is no review so there will be no tag for the code to scrape
        #It is saying if nv is True (we have a review) return the review or just put a - in
        #We now tell the code to go into the tag  'p' 'class' 'review-content__text'
        nv = container.find_all('p', attrs={'class': 'review-content__text'})
        review = container.p.text if len(nv) == True else '-'
        reviews.append(review)

        #Get the title of the review
        nv1 = container.find_all('h2', attrs={'class': 'review-content__title'})
        heading = container.a.text if len(nv1) == True else '-'
        headings.append(heading)

        #Get the star rating review given
        star = container.find("div", {"class":"star-rating star-rating--medium"}).find('img').get('alt')
        stars.append(star)

        #Get the date
        date_json = json.loads(container.find('script').text)
        date = date_json['publishedDate']
        dates.append(date)


TrustPilot = pd.DataFrame({'Title': headings, 'Body': reviews, 'Rating': stars, 'Date': dates})

print(TrustPilot)
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4929267/4727702) to learn how to debug your code

Comment: Single page applications that loads the content via API calls, returns blank as you have seen. I suspect this site to be Single page application

Comment: print(review_div) returns an empty list

Comment: In this line: `date_json = json.loads(container.find('script').text)` if that code reads the JSON object, you can get all the data without scrapping directly the HTML. Can't tell for sure the output of your current code, but, if your loop doesn't show anything, consider use `soup.select("div > article")` instead.