# doing a linear search python code for a list and for some reason im getting both conditions satisfied, can someone help me with this

Tags: python, list, linear-search

```
K=[30,15,25,50,40,35,44,49,55,54]

Search = int(input("enter the value you want to search"))
Index=0
Found=False

while Index<=9 and Found==False:
    if K[Index]==Search:
        print("Match found")
        Found=True

    else:
        print("Match not found")
        Index=Index+1
```

the result for this code when the value used are 15 comes out as;

***Match not found***

***Match found***

however, when i enter the value to be searched as 30 the results come out correctly as;

***Match found***

however when i enter 54 as the value to be searched the results come out as;

***Match not found***

***Match not found***

***Match not found***

***Match not found***

***Match not found***

***Match not found***

***Match not found***

***Match not found***

***Match not found***

***Match found***

can someone help me figure out why the results differ in this way for each value tested, what's wrong with my code
and also what do I do to fix it
also, I'm a beginner and have no idea what I'm doing yet so I might have made a dumb mistake
and also I'm aware there are easier ways of searching up values in a list
but I need to learn this specific method so please help me with this one

Comment: Don't print "Match not found" until the entire list has been searched. That is, _after_ the loop has completed and a match wasn't found.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

15 is the second item in your list `K`, and your `while` loops through every list element.

If you think about how the program runs, you'll see that the loop goes through every item in then list before `Search` is found.

So, when you enter 15, your program goes through the all elements of the list before 15. The only item before 15 is 30, so before returning `Match found` for 15, it returns `Match not found`.

Similarly, 54 is the 10th item in your list, so your program prints `Match not found` 9 times, and `Match found` on the tenth.

One solution to this would be to simply not print `Match not found` until the last element of the list has been reached.

That would look like this:

```
K = [30,15,25,50,40,35,44,49,55,54]

Search = int(input("Enter the value you want to search: "))
Index = 0
Found = False

while Index<=9 and not Found:
    if K[Index]==Search:
        print("Match found")
        Found=True
    else:
        if Index==9:
            print("Match not found")
        Index=Index+1
```

There are better ways to do this while still doing a linear search, but this method is easy to understand.

It is possible that you don't NEED to do a linear search, in which case you can use `in` to check wether a list contains something.
For example:

```
print('Found!' if Search in K else 'Not found.')
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're trying to get in your code. If you only want your code to print either `match found` or `match not found` then:

The issue that you're having is that you're iterating through every number in the list and telling your program to print out either 'match found' or 'match not found' for every single iteration. So, the first time the program goes through the while loop it checks if 30 is the same as the input number and if not it prints `match not found` and the program will print out something every iteration it goes through.

A simple solution would be to check if any of the values match and then print either `match found` or `match not found`

for example:

```
K=[30,15,25,50,40,35,44,49,55,54]

Search = int(input("enter the value you want to search"))
Index=0
Found=False

while Index<=9 and Found==False:  #technically you don't even need this (Found==False) here
    if K[Index]==Search:
        Found=True

if Found==True:
    print("Match found")
else:
    print("Match not found")
```

another solution could be to print out the `match found` in the while loop and not have an if else statement:

code:

```
K=[30,15,25,50,40,35,44,49,55,54]

Search = int(input("enter the value you want to search"))
Index=0
Found=False

while Index<=9 and Found==False: 
    if K[Index]==Search:
        print("Match found")
        Found=True

if Found==False:
    print("Match not found")
```