# not able to understand 2nd while loop in code below-:

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

```py
def summer_of69(arr):
    total =0
    add = True
    for num in arr:
        while add:
            if num!= 6:
                total+=num
                break
            else:
                add = False
        while not add:
            if num!=9:
                break
            else:
                add= True 
                break
    return total
```

In this code, if I pass `summer_of69([2,5,6,9,11])`, how 9 is getting ignored and 11 getting added?

The output I am getting 18 is correct but I want to know how 2nd while loop is working here.

After 6 how is it working for 9 and 11?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code using a debugger in a good IDE? It adds numbers up to the first 6, then skips a followup 9 and adds what follows - if there's no 9 following the 6 it doesn't get back to adding. What the point of this code is, is unsure, but that's what it does.

Comment: Pretend you are the interpreter. Instead of trying to do it in your head, use pencil and paper and execute each statement in sequence recording the result on the paper - keep track of variables, function arguments, conditional results.

Comment: [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues)
 If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features  Or the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening. 
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: [Visualize execution](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to understand how any complex system of loops works you just have to go through the code step by step and evaluate the logic the way the computer does.

When `num` becomes `6`, think about what happens when it goes through both `while` loops.

The first `while` loop does not add `6` to `total` and instead turns the variable `add` to `False`.

Since `add` is now `False` the second `while` loop triggers but then immediately breaks.

Now `num` is `9` and since `add` is `False` the first `while` loop does not execute.

Instead the second one does and `add` becomes `True`.

Finally, now that `add` is `True`, when `num` is `11`, the first `while` loop executes, adding `11` to the total and the second `while` loop does not.

It just takes a moment to think it through in your head, and if it ever becomes too complicated to do in your head, there are plenty of visualize execution programs out on the web that do it for you.