# Obtaining a TypeError in the following code (for Leetcode 46. Permutations) but can't see the issue

Tags: python, permutation

I'm seeing the following error message in my solution to this [Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/):

```
TypeError: object of type `NoneType' has no len()
    for j in range(len(elt)+1)
```

```
class Solution:

    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        
        ans = [[]]
    
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            temp = []
        
            for elt in ans:
                for j in range(len(elt)+1):
                    local = elt.copy()
                    t = local.insert(j, nums[i])
                    temp.append(t)
        
            ans = temp.copy()
    
        return ans
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems for how to solve such problems yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration of you're loop,  `t = local.append(j,nums[i])` is None because insert does not have a return type. This is because .insert() is a [mutating-method](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/mutation.html) . By invoking `temp.append(t)` (with t = None), temp becomes the `None` type aswell. Since you're invoking `ans = temp.copy()`. ans is from type `None` now aswell hence you copied the `None` type.

When reaching the for loop (`for elt in ans`), elt becomes `None`.
Therefore calling `range(len(elt)+1)` will crash, since the `None` type does not have a `len()` function.

You see that the element which became None is cascading until a Point where the program crashes. To handle such problems, iterate through the code step by step with a debugger and try to understand whats happening.

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1. Updated my post pointing out that .insert() is mutating method.

Comment: Hi, thanks to both for your comments. Just to confirm / check my understanding, I think that the link in mkrieger1's first link highlights what was going wrong in my code. local.insert(j, nums[j]) mutates local, rather than builds a new list. Am I right to think that if I ever tried to assign list.mutator() to a variable it would always just be None? I'm just checking as DrGregoryHouse's comment seems to imply there is a different issue.

Comment: Yes you are right, since mutating means altering an existent value, the functioncall rather changes the existent value than returning a new value. Hence None is returned. Btw when Comments/answers are helpful, don't forget to vote up. Also check aswers as Correct answer if they solved/clarified your problem.