# I made a guessing game and for some reason even though I used the global thing it keeps telling me that it is not defined but I did just earlier

Tags: python

This is the code. Somebody please help. I'm confused. The `guess` variable is the number of guesses that remain after each guess. I've tried `global` and it still doesn't work. I'm lost at this point. Please help.

```
import random 

# WELCOMING USER
print(" WELCOME TO THE NUMBER GUESSING GAME !! ")
print("The number you'll be guessing is between the range 1 - 100 ")

# SELECTING THE CORRECT GUESS RANDOMLY
correct_number = random.randint(1,100)

# ASKING THE USER FOR PREFERED DIFFICULTY AND SETTING NO OF GUESSES 
difficulty_mode  = input("Do you want the game to be easy or hard ? : ").lower()
guess = 0
#testing purposes
print(correct_number)

if difficulty_mode  == "hard":
    guess = 5 
    print("You have 5 guesses")
elif difficulty_mode == "easy" :
    guess = 10
    print(f"You have {guess} guesses")
else:
    print("Wrong input")

# CREATING A FUNCTION TO REDUCE NO OF GUESSES 
def reducing_guesses () :
    global guess
    guess -= 1
    print(f"You have {guess} no. of guesses remaining ")

# CREATING A WHILE LOOP TO RUN GAME 

isTrue = True 
loop_rounds = 0
# ACTUAL WHILE LOOP
while isTrue  == True :
    if guess == 0:
        isTrue = False
        winning_or_loose = 0
    if loop_rounds > 0 :
        user_guess = int(input("Guess again : "))
        if user_guess  == correct_number :
            isTrue == False
            print(f"You win! You guessed:{user_guess} and it was correct ")
            winning_or_loose = 1
        else:
            reducing_guesses()
    if loop_rounds  == 0 :
        user_guess = int(input("Make a guess :"))
        if user_guess == correct_number :
            isTrue  = False 
            print(f"You win! You guessed:{user_guess} and it was correct ")
            winning_or_loose = 1 
        else:
            reducing_guesses()
```

Comment: Your question suggests that you are finding `guess` is undefined, but when I run your code, I see that `user_guess` is undefined.

Comment: I've never had to fix EVERY LINE of someone's post. Please be more diligent when posting your questions.

Comment: add `user_guess = 0` somewhere before your `while` loop

Comment: [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues)
 If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features  Or the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening. 
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is put `user_guess = 0` and `winning_or_loose = 0` somewhere before your `while` loop, and it fixes your game. Your main issue seems to be that you keep trying to use variables that you never created.

However, you code has a lot of redundancy, and is not organized very well. You have no system in place to handle the user entering bad data. There is no way to play your game a second time, without restarting. Consider the following version of your game. I provide it to you as a somewhat optimized example. It is not perfect. It illustrates how to get rid of about half of your code for the same (or better) results.

You may want to incorporate a system that tells the user if the `correct_number` is higher or lower than their guess. Currently, your game is practically impossible to win. It's like trying to play a 3D shooter that has no lights, at all. This suggestion is not implemented in the below code.

```
import random 

#GAME LOOP
while True:
    # WELCOMING USER
    print(" WELCOME TO THE NUMBER GUESSING GAME !! ")
    print("The number you'll be guessing is in the range 1 - 100 ")
    
    #ALL VARIABLES
    won            = 0
    guess          = 0
    user_guess     = 0
    loop_rounds    = 0
    msg            = ('Make a guess : ', 'Guess again : ')
    correct_number = random.randint(1,100)
    
    # ASKING THE USER FOR PREFERED DIFFICULTY AND SETTING NO OF GUESSES 
    while (in_ := input("Do you want the game to be easy or hard ? : ").lower()) not in ('easy','hard'):
        print("Wrong input")
        
    guess = (10,5)[in_=='hard']
    
    #ROUND LOOP
    while guess>0:
        print(f"You have {guess} no. of guesses remaining ")
        
        while not (in_ := input(msg[loop_rounds>0])).isdigit():
            print('Input a number between 1 and 100')
            
        user_guess = int(in_)
        
        if user_guess == correct_number :
            print(f"You win! You guessed:{user_guess} and it was correct ")
            won += 1 
            break
            
        guess -= 1
        loop_rounds += 1
           
    #LOST           
    if user_guess != correct_number:
        print('You failed to guess the number.')
        
    #PLAY AGAIN
    if input('Try again(y,n)? ') == 'n':
        break
```