# How to manipulate and return a string from a recursive function?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, graph, depth-first-search

I wrote the recursive code to get the path taken in a DFS traversal, but I want to get the output into a string variable. Recursion is not my strong suit so I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out the what to return. Here's the code I wrote for the algorithm

```
adj_lst = [None, [3, 4], [3], [1, 2], [1]]
size = len(adj_lst)
visited = [False] * size

def dfs(starting_node, a_lst, output):
    visited[starting_node] = True
    output += str(starting_node)

    for vertex in a_lst[starting_node]:

        if visited[vertex] == False:
            visited[vertex] = True
            dfs(vertex, a_lst, output)

    return output


print(dfs(1,adj_lst,''))
```

I give an adjacency list of an undirected graph where the index corresponds to the parent node and the list inside contains the child nodes. Every time a node gets visited, I add that node to the `output` variable and return it in the end.

In this case the desired output is "1 3 2 4" but what I get is "1"

Comment: `for vertex in a_lst[starting_node]:` here is bug I think. You just look at the starting node, disregarding all the others

Comment: It is a bad idea to use recursion for DFS.  It can be made to work for small graphs, but it is not saleable to large graphs since you run out of memory.  Take a look ay DFS algorithms using a stack or queue which are both simpler and scalable to huge graphs.

Comment: `dfs(vertex, a_lst, output)` - this won't return a result to the calling function. Try `return dfs(vertex, a_lst, output)`.

Comment: A good IDE will allow you to trace a recursive process.

Comment: [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues)
 If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features  Or the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening. 
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
adj_lst = [None, [3, 4], [3], [1, 2], [1]]
size = len(adj_lst)
visited = [False] * size

def dfs(starting_node, a_lst, output):
    visited[starting_node] = True
    output += str(starting_node)

    for vertex in a_lst[starting_node]:
        if visited[vertex] == False:
            visited[vertex] = True
            output = dfs(vertex, a_lst, output)

    return output


print(dfs(1,adj_lst,''))
```