# Using the same iterator in nested for loops

Tags: python, nested, iterator, generator, nested-loops

Consider the following code:

```
from itertools import chain

lst = ['a', 1, 2, 3, 'b', 4, 5, 'c', 6]

def nestedForLoops():
    it = iter(lst)
    for item0 in it:
        if isinstance(item0, str):
            print(item0)
        else:
            # this shouldn't happen because of
            # 1. lst[0] is a str, and
            # 2. line A
            print(f"this shouldn't happen: {item0=}")
            pass
        for item1 in it:
            if not isinstance(item1, int):
                break
            print(f'\t{item1}')
        else: # no-break
            # reached end of iterator
            return
        # reached a str
        assert isinstance(item1, str)
        it = chain(item1, it) # line A

nestedForLoops()
```

I was expecting it to print

```
a
    1
    2
    3
b
    4
    5
c
    6
```

but instead it printed

```
a
    1
    2
    3
this shouldn't happen: item0=4
this shouldn't happen: item0=5
c
this shouldn't happen: item0=6
```

I wrote what I thought was equivalent code using `while` loops instead of for loops:

```
from itertools import chain

lst = ['a', 1, 2, 3, 'b', 4, 5, 'c', 6]

def nestedWhileLoops():
    it = iter(lst)
    while True:
        try:
            item0 = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        if isinstance(item0, str):
            print(item0)
        else:
            # this shouldn't happen because of
            # 1. lst[0] is a str, and
            # 2. line B
            print(f"this shouldn't happen: {item0=}")
            pass
        while True:
            try:
                item1 = next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                # reached end of iterator
                return
            if not isinstance(item1, int):
                break
            print(f'\t{item1}')
        # reached a str
        assert isinstance(item1, str)
        it = chain(item1, it) # line B

nestedWhileLoops()
```

and this `while` loop version does print what I expected, namely

```
a
    1
    2
    3
b
    4
    5
c
    6
```

So why does `nestedForLoops` behave differently than `nestedWhileLoops`?

Comment: When you stepped through `nestedForLoops` with your debugger did each line behave as  you intended? [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues)
 If you are using an IDE now is a good time to learn its debugging features. Printing stuff at strategic points can help you trace what is or isn't happening. 
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @wwii very good advice! I did step through the code with the debugger, but did not know how to explain the behavior I was seeing. It would have been more helpful of me to mention this in the question as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a `for` loop is entered, the current iterator it is using cannot be re-assigned until the outside of that scope is reached.

Here:

```
for item0 in it:
```

You start iterating over `it` and continue in the scope of this `for` loop until the end of the function.

When you reassign `it` within its scope:

```
it = chain(item1, it) # line A
```

It has no effect on the iterator you are already iterating over.

The reason it "kind of" works for the inner `for` loop is because you exit the scope of that `for` loop on each string.

So in short, your `for` loop example does the following:

1. Enter the outer `for` loop and start iterating the original `it`
2. Enter the inner `for` loop and continue iterating the original `it`
3. Exit inner `for` loop scope and re-assign `it`
4. In outer scope, continue iterating the original `it`
5. Re-enter the inner `for` loop and start iterating over the newly assigned `it`
6. Repeat 3 through 6

Doing something like this may give you a better understanding:

```
it = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for item in it:
    print(item)
    it = None
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
```

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop includes an implicit call to `iter` to get an iterator for the given *iterable*. Once you get that iterator, you *cannot* modify it. Assigning a *new* iterable to the name `it` doesn't affect the outer loop, because the outer loop only looks at the value bound to `it` when the loop *starts*.

With your `while` loop, you make explicit calls to `next(it)`, meaning you have the opportunity to change the value associated with the name `it` between calls. The implicit calls to `next` made by the `for` loop don't use the name `it` as its argument; the loop has its *own*, private reference to the original iterator, and you can't modify that iterator. (`chain(item, it)` creates a *new* iterator, rather than modifying the one `it` currently refers to.)