# how to fix int object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, runtime-error

this is my code currently:

```
previous = 0
count = 0
counts = []
item = str(data)

for x in range(len(item)):
    if dates[x][3] != previous[3] or dates[x][4] != previous[4]:
            if negative[x] != "No Negative":
                counts.append(count)
                count = 0
    count += 1
    previous = dates[x]


print(counts)
```

I keep getting an "'int' object is not subscriptable error. my values for dates and data are lists and I'm assuming the issue is that they aren't strings but nothing I do fixes the error.

thank you

Comment: It means that you are trying to do something like this: `10[0]`.

Comment: Please always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`).

Comment: [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues).  If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features  Printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening. [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: `previous = 0` - `previous` is an int on the first iteration.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in `previous[3]`.

`previous` is `int`, it's not subscriptable.