# Checking if filename prefixes match parent directory prefix recursively with pathlib

Tags: python, list, pathlib

I've written a script that uses pathlib to compare a list of files provided by the user to what is actually in a target directory. It then returns lists of files that were expected but not found, and files that were found but were not expected. It works just fine.

My issue now is that I want to verify that filename prefixes match the prefix of their parent directory, and return an error when they don't. So a folder named `abc2022_001` should contain files that start with `abc2022_` and not `abc2023_`. This is what I have so far:

```
from pathlib import Path

fileList = open("fileList.txt", "r")
data = fileList.read()
fileList_reformatted = data.replace('\n', '').split(",")
print(fileList_reformatted)

p = Path('C:/Users/Common/Downloads/compare').rglob('*')
filePaths = [x for x in p if x.is_file()]
filePaths_string = [str(x) for x in filePaths]
print(filePaths_string)

differences1 = []
for element in fileList_reformatted:
    if element not in filePaths_string:
        differences1.append(element)

print("The following files from the provided list were not found:",differences1)

differences2 = []
for element in filePaths_string:
    if element not in fileList_reformatted:
        differences2.append(element)

print("The following unexpected files were found:",differences2)

wrong_location = []
for element in p:
    if element.Path.name.split("_")[0:1] != element.Path.parent.split("_")[0:1]:
        wrong_location.append(element)
    
print("Following files may be in the wrong location:",wrong_location)
```

The script runs, but returns no errors on a test directory. Where am I going wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues)

Comment: Not enough information, please read [mre]. You need to provide minimal examples of  `fileList_reformatted` and `filePaths`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be:

```
for element in filePaths:
if element.parts[-1].split("_")[0] != element.parent.parts[-1].split("_")[0]:
```

Thanks for helping, folks.

Comment: Glad you solved it! These kinds of errors are always annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You could try just picking the first element from the splits in this line.

```
if element.Path.name.split("_")[0:1] != element.Path.parent.split("_")[0:1]:
```

like so

```py
 if element.Path.name.split("_")[0] != element.Path.parent.split("_")[0]:
```

The first version compares two lists `['abc22'] == ['abc23']` and not the actual values `'abc22' == 'abc23'`. That might be the cause.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately it doesn't seem to solve the issue.