# understanding autotest results in codegrade for python

Tags: python

I am a beginner coder and have assignments in codegrade for school which are autograded. The problem is I don't know how to interpret the results of the autograde. I have an assignment that is running fine but when I autograde it fails the tests.

Originally the last line of my code was

```
print(repr(firstword_minus + secondword_minus))
```

When I didn't use `repr()` and instead used `str()` it told me that "the string contains only whitespace, escaping them using repr()".

Here is the resulting failure on the autotest results when I used `repr()`:

```
inputs:  "hello", "world"
 E   assert "''\n" == 'elloorld\n'
  - elloorld
  + ''
```

In the assignment description it wants you to concatenate two words together without their first letter, and without any quotations. I don't have quotes in the string for the final line so I'm not sure what the error means.

Here is the full code using `str()`:

```
firstword = input('Give me the first word: ')
secondword = input('Give me the second word: ')
firstlength = len(firstword)
firstlength = str(firstlength)
firstword_minus = (firstlength[1:])
secondlength = len(secondword)
secondlength = str(secondlength)
secondword_minus = (secondlength[1:])
print(str(firstword_minus + secondword_minus))
```

If someone could explain how to interpret these results, ie. how to know what I did wrong on this assignment I would appreciate it so that in future assignments I understand how to read and interpret failed autotests.

Comment: "I don't have quotes in the string for the final line" - yes you do, `repr()` adds them.

Comment: Beside the point, but `firstlength = str(firstlength)` doesn't make any sense. You don't even need to get anything's `len()` in the first place so I'm not sure how you got to this point.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a good first question! Very clear! Keep it up :) But if you do want tips, check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The autograde results are to be interpreted like this:

```
 - elloorld
```

The autograder expected to see `elloorld` as output of your code, but it did not see it.

```
 + ''
```

The autograder saw `''` (i.e. two quotation marks, not an empty string) as output of your code but it did not expect to see this.

This means that you made two or more mistakes:

- You used `repr()` which, when given a string, returns that string with additional quotation marks around it (or if you didn't use `repr()`, the autograder used it anyway because the output of your code was empty, in order to make it display better).
- The string `firstword_minus + secondword_minus` that was passed to `repr()` was empty (meaning that those two variables were empty strings as well).

Comment: If possible could you explain why the variables would have been empty strings?

Comment: It would be possible but I would rather leave that to you as an exercise in [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues).

Answer (score -1):

I deleted the lines of code where I used len() as suggested above, they weren't necessary to the code as the length of the word didn't matter, only that the first letter was deleted. I don't know why, but after I deleted these lines the code ran correctly. I used str() instead of repr() in the code so that the quotes weren't present in the final string.

corrected code:

```
firstword = input('Give me the first word: ')
secondword = input('Give me the second word: ')
firstlength = str(firstword)
firstword_minus = (firstlength[1:])
secondlength = str(secondword)
secondword_minus = (secondlength[1:])
print(str( firstword_minus + secondword_minus ))
```

thx!

Comment: I hate to say you're wrong about your own answer, but the question you asked is only about how to interpret the results of the grader, not about what's wrong with your code. Normally I'd say to post a new question with this as an answer, but questions that were caused by unexplained mistakes (like typos) are not considered useful here. (For reference see [On-Topic under "Some questions ... may be closed"](/help/on-topic).)