How to tackle TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
I want to build a scrapper. And I wrote this code, it keeps on running into error. I would be grateful if anyone can help.
import requests
import pandas as pd

def fetch_json(api_link, timeout=10):
    try:
        response = requests.get(api_link, timeout=timeout)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.json()
        else:
            print(f"Failed to fetch data from API for link: {api_link}")
            return None
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        print(f"Timeout occurred while fetching data for link: {api_link}. Skipping...")
        return None
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error occurred while fetching data for link {api_link}: {e}")
        return None

api_link = "https://apiv2.cricket.com.au/web/players/list?isActive=1&teamId=&jsconfig=eccn%3Atrue&format=json"

player_data= fetch_json(api_link)

name = []

if player_data:
    players = player_data['players']
    for player in players:
        id = "".join(players['id'])
        displayname = "".join(players['displayname'])
        name.append({
            "id" : player.get("id"),
            "displayname" : player.get("displayname")
        })
    print(f"Player Name Retrieved")
    
player_name = pd.DataFrame(name)

It shows error along the id column and I can't seem to solve this problem.

id = player['id'], displayname = player['displayName']. "player" not "players", no need for join, and displayName case was wrong in other places too.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/4929251/235698

As mentioned in the comment, your code has some simple typos when referring to the values in the json data. For each player in the list of players use:
player['id']
player['displayName']
name.append(
        {"id" : player['id'],
        "displayname" : player['displayName']
        })


This is the sample data:
{'id': 2786, 'firstName': 'Khaliq', 'lastName': 'Noori', 'middleName': 'Dad', 'displayName': 'Khaliq Dad', 'nationality': '', 'gender': '', 'teams': [{'id': 6, 'name': 'Afghanistan Men', 'isWomensTeam': False}], 'isActive': True}
As you can see, you need to change from "players" and "displayname" to "players" and "displayName" respectively. Also, there is no need to use join here.
if player_data:
    players = player_data['players']
    for player in players:
        id = player['id']
        displayname = player['displayName']
        name.append({
            "id": id,
            "displayname": displayname
        })
    print("Player Names Retrieved")
    
player_name = pd.DataFrame(name)


