Convergence of Coordinate Descent
I am trying to implement the algorithms described in the paper Learning Fast Approximations of Sparse Coding and completed the ISTA and FISTA algorithms and the dictionary update rule using projected block coordinate descent.
I ran into a problem while implementing Coordinate Descent (Algorithm 2 in the paper) for approximating the optimal sparse codes though, since the code does not seem to converge. A similar problem occurred with ISTA too, but I quickly figured out that the learning rate was smaller than the largest eigenvalue of DTD, which violates one of the convergence criteria. However, since the Coordinate Descent algorithm does not have such hyperparameters except the regularization, I am confused.
I got some suggestions to try tweaking the regularization parameter, but it does not seem to help a bit.
Minimal reproducible example
import torch
import itertools

def shrink(a, b):
    return torch.sign(a) * torch.maximum(torch.abs(a) - b, torch.tensor(0.0))

def change(a, b):
    return torch.sum(torch.abs(a - b))

def CoD(x : torch.Tensor,
         h_dim : int,
         D : torch.Tensor,
         regularization=0.5,
         frequency=None) -> torch.Tensor:
    """
    Implements the Coordinate Descent algorithm to find the optimal
    sparse codes for the given input vector x and a given
    dictionary matrix D. This function follows notation corresponding to
    the paper "Learning Fast Approximations of Sparse Coding"

    :param x: The input vector
    :param h_dim: Dimension of sparse code required. In
    the overcomplete case, should be greater than or equal to
    dim(x).
    :param D: the dictionary matrix
    :param regularization: parameter which controls the relative
    weight given to sparsity vs reconstruction loss
    :param lr: the learning rate
    :param frequency: the number of iterations after which an update is printed
    :return: An approximation to the optimal sparse code of the
    given input h_opt.
    """
    n = x.shape[0]
    m = h_dim
    assert D.shape == (n, m), (f"D should be matrix of shape (x_dim, h_dim), where "
                               f"x_dim={n} and h_dim={m}, but dimensions of D are {D.shape}")
    z = torch.zeros(h_dim)
    z_old = z.clone()

    S = torch.eye(h_dim) - torch.matmul(torch.transpose(D, 0, 1), D)
    B = torch.matmul(D.T, x)

    counter = itertools.count(start=0, step=1)
    while True:
        z = shrink(B, regularization)
        k = torch.argmax(torch.abs(z - z_old))
        for j in range(m):
            B[j] = B[j] + S[j][k] * (z[k] - z_old[k])
        if change(z, z_old) < 0.01:
            break
        z_old = z.clone()
        iter_num = next(counter)
        if frequency is not None and iter_num % frequency == 0:
            print(f"Coordinate Descent: Iteration {iter_num}")
    return shrink(B, regularization)

print(CoD(torch.randn(10), 10, torch.randn(10, 10), frequency=100))

I tried to implement the algorithm almost exactly as described in the paper. Can someone help me with the debugging process?
I checked the logs and the values of $Z, \bar{Z}$ and B keep growing exponentially large until they go to infinity and become nans.

What was your question again?

@mkrieger1 Debugging. Added it to the body.

Do you mean as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues?

Not really. The code is working.There is some error with the way I implemented it since it is not converging. I wanna find that logic error

Did you try to ask GPT for that ? He found interesting stuff on your implementation, but my mathematical knowledge cannot say if it's ok or not: https://chatgpt.com/share/67731361-f070-8007-818a-44cf1a7e8057

@tito I wouldn't really ask here before consulting GPT :) Trust me I've tried for 4-5 days
