How do you go about debugging a program?
Ive written my first program in Python. Its taken over a year and is 2700 lines long, uses files, produces files, PDF, nothing complicated, just a lot of sequential and repeated functions just changing some internal details.
It stopped working when I removed and reinstalled Pycharm. I repaired it with a combination of blind luck and ChatGPT, but realised it clearly wasnt a very well designed program, and the fixes were making it even messier.
So I've decided to re-write it, but am getting totally lost in the debugging. For example, changing something in function A, I just keep getting lost hopping from f(A) to functions (B) and (C) etc, that either use the return or supply the parameters, and I'm just getting more and more confused and making the mess even bigger.
My question is: How do you debug/improve a program? Do you need half a dozen screens open at the same time? Do you print it out so you can reference the code? How do you keep track of stuff that seems to work like the "Butterfly Effect", changing one tiny parameter in one spot that wrecks something somewhere else?
Is there a "proper" method? Can you recommend any books or sites or programs that might help learn a tried and tested method?
Not necessary, but if anyone's interested, here's the (old) code.
https://github.com/Drewpskovacs/Breadth_Monitor/blob/main/Breadth_Monitor.py
Thanks

We use a debugger? Like https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues

https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Your first program is 2700 lines long? That's very ambitious for a first step.

The real question that you should be asking is, how to structure a project so that it's easier to debug and that it's not so intertwined that making minor changes somewhere breaks an unrelated part somewhere else. And the answer to that for the most part is unfortunately "experience and learning from your mistakes." Looking into TDD might also be useful.

Yes. That makes sense. More time planning.
