# How can I see my compiled code in machine language/assembly?

Tags: c, assembly

I would like to see, after compiling some code (for example C), the resulting code in machine language or assembly. How can that be done?

Comment: What system / compiler?

Comment: Check this site: https://godbolt.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the GCC documentation (assuming gcc) found at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options:

> -S
>       Stop after the stage of compilation proper; do not assemble. The output is in the form of an assembler code file for each non-assembler input file specified.
>       By default, the assembler file name for a source file is made by replacing the suffix ‘.c’, ‘.i’, etc., with ‘.s’.
>       Input files that don’t require compilation are ignored.

For example, `gcc -S hello.c` would output an assembly file named `hello.s`.

Answer (score 3):

Many compilers (including `gcc` and `clang`) have an `-S` option that makes them output assembly instead of a binary file.

Alternatively you can view the assembly for an existing binary file using a disassembler. For example `objdump` from the GNU binutils can show you the assembly for a given binary using the `-d` (`--disassemble`) or `-D` (`--disassemble-all`) options.

Answer (score 0):

compile your code with the -g flag, and run with gdb

```
gcc -g main.c
gdb a.exe
```

and in gdb:

```
(gdb) layout asm
```

There is more info in a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902901/show-current-assembly-instruction-in-gdb)

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling your source code: `gcc -S file.c`

If you don't have the source code, just the binary file: `objdump -d exe`