# Make gdb display assembly instructions instead of C

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switching to assembly in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589653/switching-to-assembly-in-gdb)

I am debugging some code in gdb. When I run the `ni` (for *next instruction*) command, it displays the C code. Displaying the executed assembly instructions would make more sense to me.

```
(gdb) ni
0x0804845a  28          tmp = *lpp;
(gdb) ni
0x0804845c  28          tmp = *lpp;
(gdb) ni
0x0804846a  29          **lpp = (unsigned long) &buf;
(gdb) ni
0x0804846c  29          **lpp = (unsigned long) &buf;
```

Is there any way to make gdb display the assembly code instead, without calling `disassm` every time?

**EDIT:** I know about the `layout asm` command which displays the code in a readline window. I would like to see the disassembly on the gdb commandline, not in a gdb window.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth not an exact duplicate but one of the answers (not the accepted one) answers this question.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov: Yes, I always look for duplicate answers, not questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you step via `ni`, displaying the next handful of assembly instructions is often very useful.

```
(gdb) display/4i $pc
```

will show the next 4 instructions every time GDB stops.

Answer (score 10):

Did you try to use TUI ASM layout?

It's fairly handy.

```
(gdb) layout asm
```